# Issue setting checkboxes to disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress-mvc

I am currently working on a project where the permissions of the site's users and their permissions are being displayed within a DevExpress GridView.  The user's permissions are simply checkboxes.  An issue I'm running across is setting the object for the checkbox.

Originally, the site was used only by one entity (ie. office).  My goal is to make is used by multiple offices.  To accomplish this, I created a dropdown to switch between the offices so that you can set a user's permissions based on each office.  However, each office does not have the same list of permissions.

Ex. The first office has full access to the site (12 modules) (it was the original office).  The second office only has access to 5 modules on the site.  I created a method to take care of this issue that disables everything but the 5 modules for the second office.

On development, what I created to handle this works.  However, when moved to our testing enviroment, it stopped working.  The issue I believe is there are two foreach loops used to create the checkbox field, along with the column data of the grid.  Below is what I have done to make my solution work.

View

```
foreach (var item in Model.Applications)
        {
            settings.Columns.AddBand(bnd =>
            {
                bnd.Name = string.Format("{0}", item.Name);
                bnd.Caption = item.Name + " Roles";

                foreach (var subitem in item.Roles)
                {
                    bnd.Columns.Add(col =>
                    {
                        col.Name = string.Format("{0}", subitem.Name);
                        col.FieldName = subitem.Name;
                        col.VisibleIndex = index;
                        col.Width = Unit.Pixel(75);
                        col.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.CheckBox;
                        col.Caption = subitem.Description;
                        col.Settings.AllowAutoFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
                        col.Settings.AllowHeaderFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
                        col.Settings.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;

                        col.SetDataItemTemplateContent(temp =>
                        {
                        %>
                        <%=Html.CheckBox(
                                string.Format("chk{0}{1}", col.Name, temp.KeyValue.ToString().Replace("-", "")),
                                (bool)DataBinder.Eval(temp.DataItem, col.Name),
                                SCCView.Areas.Admin.Models.ModifyPrivilegeModel.GetHtmlAttributes(bnd.Name, temp.KeyValue, col.Name, item.Name)
                                )%>
                        <%
                        });
                    });
                    index++;
                }
            });
        }
```

Model

```
public static object GetHtmlAttributes(string bndName, object keyValue, string colName, string itemName)
        {
            //Check to see if SCNGO is being used
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["SCNGOAllowedApps"] != null)
            {
                //Check to see if that Application is within SCNGO currently
                var scngoApps = (List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Session["SCNGOAllowedApps"];
                var app = scngoApps.Where(scngo => scngo == itemName).Select(scngo => scngo).FirstOrDefault();

                //App is not, so disable it
                if (app == null)
                    return new
                    {
                        onClick = string.Format(@"CheckChanged(this, '{0}', '{1}', '{2}');",
                                       bndName,
                                       keyValue,
                                       colName),
                        Class = "ModifyPrivChkBox",
                        disabled = "disabled"
                    };
            }

            //SCC, or at the very least an app within SCNGO
            return new
            {
                onClick = string.Format(@"CheckChanged(this, '{0}', '{1}', '{2}');",
                                        bndName,
                                        keyValue,
                                        colName),
                Class = "ModifyPrivChkBox"
            };
        }
```

On development, the checkboxes are disabled.  On our test site, they are not.  I have looked to see if the Session I used to do this is there or not and it is.  The issue is timing I believe.  The app variable I created always ends up with the last entry in the list, thus always allowing the checkbox to not be disabled.

My question is is there a way to deal with this timing issue and make this more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue at long last.  The problem was the itemName.  It was constantly coming back as the same value regardless of where in the loop it was.  Once I changed it to colName, it suddenly began working.